# C function to count unique columns in an array

Tags: c

Have a problem in writing working function for a program, function needs to go give out number of columns in which column elements do not repeat.

For example for Array:

- 1 2 3 4
- 1 3 1 1
- 2 2 2 2

The uniqueColumns in this case would be:

- 3 4
- 1 1
- 2 2

And program should give out: 2!

And here's the code part,

```
int uniqueColumns = 0;
int fail;

for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < totalColumns; currentColumn++)
{
    fail = 0;
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < totalRows; currentRow++)
    {
        for (int rowOffset = currentRow + 1; currentRow < totalRows; currentRow++)
        {
            if (array[currentRow][currentColumn] == array[currentRow+rowOffset][currentColumn])
            {
                fail = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                fail = 0;
            }
        }
        if (fail == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fail == 0)
    {
        uniqueColumns++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the missing question is "Why does my code not work?"

---

It may not be your only problem but it must be one.  You are comparing:

```
array[currentRow][currentColumn] == array[currentRow+rowOffset][currentColumn]
```

when your `rowOffset` ranges from `currentRow+1` upwards.  This is clearly not what you wanted.  It would be OK if you compared

```
array[currentRow][currentColumn] == array[rowOffset][currentColumn]
```

or have `rowOffset` range from 1 upwards.

---

I may be completely wrong, but I presume this is a programming exercise.  If it is so, I think it's very probable that your instructor wants you to do something more clever for detecting duplicate elements, instead of comparing all pairs.  Do you know anything about the values of the array's elements?  If yes, can you think of something better?

Comment: the values of the elements are generated automatically in main prog,
and Iam not trying to compare all pairs. Atleast I hope Iam not, cause my aim was to compare current row element with all the next elements in the column.

Comment: Do you know anything about their minimum and maximum values?

Comment: For now Iam testing the code with random integer numbers from 0 to 10